# Identity Server 4 internal API

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 and adding more API end points to be used but I can't seem to make it working correctly. When I send a call to identity server api with access token it says

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed.
```

And API name Claims is not in access token. I am using DB configuration stores.

Here how I have configured Identity server 4.

**Startup.cs**

```
    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options=>
                {
                    // example of setting options
                    options.Tokens.ChangePhoneNumberTokenProvider = "Phone";

                    // password settings chosen due to NIST SP 800-63
                    options.Password.RequiredLength = 3; // personally i'd prefer to see 10+
                    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddMvc();

            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(StartupDevelopment).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                    {
                        options.Discovery.CustomEntries.Add("Claims", "/api/claims");                         
                    }
                )                
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()             
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConfigurationStore"),
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })                
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OperationalStore"),
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
//                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
//                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                })               
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("token", isAuth =>
                {
                    isAuth.Authority = IdentityServerConfigurations.Authority;
                    isAuth.ApiName = "claims"; // TODO change this name to refelect broader api changes
                    isAuth.RequireHttpsMetadata = IdentityServerConfigurations.Ssl;
                });
```

**Config.cs**

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvc",
                    ClientName = "MVC Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                    RequireConsent = false,

                    AccessTokenLifetime = 300,                           
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,                                                                    
                    ClientSecrets = 
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44383/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44383/signout-callback-oidc" },


                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                        "claims"                               
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true
                }
```

In **ClaimsController**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "token")]
```

Comment: Is that the startup class for your identityServer or the API that is protected under the IdentityServer?

Comment: Do you want the MVC client to be able to use the Claims API?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(“token” ?

Comment: @aaronR I am trying to add extra points in Identity server so I can use other functionalities. This startup is IdentityServer 4 startup class.

Comment: The startup class you have is what is more like what the API would have and not IdentityServer4

Comment: That startup is more like adding other API end points to your IdentityServer4 implementation where your IdentityServer4 would also host your claims API.

Comment: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/add_apis.html

Comment: Where is the rest of your startup class?

Comment: Please see updated question for full startup class code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166368/discussion-between-epistemologist-and-aaronr).

Comment: Try removing the second entry to add the developer certificate

Comment: Still same problem. IDX10214: Audience validation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I was missing configuration to request a scope from client side.

**options.Scope.Add("claims");**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")                
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Scope.Add("claims");
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see token validation implementation here, which is what is used for "token".

You need to implement Token Validation Handler if you want it to be able to use the token to access the custom api (with the "token").

Please have a look at the documentation for example on how this is done:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html#refprotectingapis

Comment: I implemented it using documentation.

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/add_apis.html

Comment: Great so you implemented token validation as well? Because that is prerequisite

Comment: What token implementation. I think 

services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("token", isAuth =>
                {
                    isAuth.Authority = "https://localhost:44387";
                    isAuth.ApiName = "claims";
                    isAuth.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                });

covers it up

Comment: This code supposed to take care of token validation but I am stuck at inserting audience in access token.